# trying to detect distortion in sloped line data

Tags: c#, c++, math, arduino, linear-algebra

I'm a starter in Arduino and C# and I got a data set from my arduino which i try to analyze using c# and some coding math.

The problem i have is this.
It are measurements of real data it represents a sloped line (up or down) the angle of this slope is not exact the same for all measurement samples. so its a bit like a line drawn by a young child.
However.. and this is the part i need to detect, sometimes i have data samples that are much more straight up.. like an apartment on a roof of a house.

ea

```
     1.0002
     2.0301
     3.023
     4.002   // if this happens for more then 4 samples
     4.005   //  i need to detect it
     4.700   //
     4.300   // (or i perhaps check if it happens more then 10 samples
     4.011   // (but for the sample i'll use 4 here
     4.910
     5.011   // the slope here is close to  y=x+1
     6.145   // but i've seen y=x-0.2 as well and other slopes.
     7.001   // i just cant asume its x+1
```

I wonder how to tackle this measurement feature.
I'm using c# here and not arduino c++ since i want to put it on screen.

i was thinking

```
 //  M(x) is my measurement
 for (x = 0;x < endofline;x++)
 {
 slope = (M[x]+M[x-1]+M[x-2]+M[x-3] ) /4
 distance = abs(M[x]-slope)+abs(M[x-1]-slope)+abs(M[x-2])
          + abs(M[x-3])+abs(M[x-4]);
 if (distance < 1) { //detected  
                     //but should this be <1   ???

                    output("detected at " + x-4); 
                    }
}
```

I'm not realy sure if this is the correct fast way to do this, or that this might give me false positives.

Comment: Do you mean, comparing the local slope to some threshold?

Comment: yes its like sloped most of the time under an unknown angle but then suddenly it can stay a while around the same value (ea vertical, or horizontal depending if you plot it on x or y axis

Comment: Pick a slope you consider "steep" and compare your slopes to that value.